# ORDER BY clause won't work with a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$Ordering=$_POST["fname"];
$CustName=$_POST["CustName"];

echo "Ordering----HHH".$Ordering."HHH".'</br>';

$query="SELECT * FROM Chargebacks WHERE CustName= '$CustName' ORDER BY '$Ordering'";
```

Both `fname` and `CustName` come from another page. `fname` works fine, `CustName` is echoed correctly as `$Ordering` ( the "HHH" is there so I could be sure there were not sneaky spaces ....)

The **ORDER BY** clause simply does nothing...if an invalid column heading is entered, the sript simply crashes as expected, but if a valid one is used, the order of results is simply the order they appear in the source table. 
If I copy and paste the value of the echoed `$Ordering` and put it in the code (without the single quotes) then the **ORDER BY** clause works fine.

In research, I have found any number of variations on a theme of single and double quotes, and normal, square and brace bracketes, but none of them has worked and I am sure such things should not be necessary. 

It is such simple thing...isn't it ?

Comment: which `mysql` API are you using? There are several: `mysql`, `mysqli`, and `PDO_mysql`. Also, The predicate in your ORDER BY clause needs to be the name of a column in your table. It's not clear whether that's the case here or not.

Comment: Before this goes into production, please, for the love of all that is holy read about SQL Injection.

Comment: Putting quotes around your `order by` value turns it into a STRING, not a field name.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried removing the quotes from around `$Ordering` within your statement?  You said yourself that if you remove the quotes and replace it with the content of the variable it works.

Answer (score 0):

1) $Ordering must be a table attribute from the table Chargebacks 
2) remove the single quotes from both side of $Ordering

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just need to concatenate these variables correctly.

```php
$query="SELECT * FROM Chargebacks WHERE CustName='".$CustName."' ORDER BY `".$Ordering."`";
```

Also , don't use single quotes, since thats making SQL treat it as a string. Use either apostrophe (`) or nothing :)

Shai.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting of a column name (`$Ordering` representing a field name) should not be necessary.
If you must quote the identifier, use `.

For the quoting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html